# Magento - change email in forgotpassword before check it

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer

In forgot password form, i need to get the email and change it before magento check it.

Why?, beacuse i need to change a customer personal number like 9834592845 to their email store in database (bla@ble.bli)

i work with the event:
controller_action_predispatch_customer_account_forgotpassword

but i can't get the email, i tried

```
$username = $observer->getRequest()->getPost('email');
$username = $observer->getRequest()->getPost();
$postData = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost();
$username = $observer->getData('email');
$username = $observer->getEmail();
$username = $_POST;
$username = $_POST['login']['username'];
$username = $_POST['login']['email'];
Mage::log($username);
```

and more, but nothing.

What i'm doing wrong.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Magento StackExchange. I don't quite understand your problem. You want to change the customer email before they access the form OR after they submitted the form ?

Answer (score 0):

Without using observer you can override the account controller forgotpasswordpostAction then you get the email and you can do whatever you want.